# Run-Time Error '438' object doesn't support this property or method error

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to loop through a spreadsheet with two date values to determine the number of months between the two dates.  My activecell is "J2" and the comparison values are in "B2" and "C2" respectively.  I'm attempting to use the DateDiff function to return the number of months between the two date values.
I was running a test on the code and encountered the following error message:

> "Run-Time Error '438' object doesn't support this property or method"

I get the error message on the last line of code listed and don't understand why I'm getting the error on the activecell.offset.  I searched through similar questions, but was unable to find an answer for my problem.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Sub tstdate()

Dim IDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
Dim HDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
Dim cnt As Integer   ' Declare variables.


    Range("j2").Select
    Do Until cnt = 7
'
    IDate = ActiveCell.OffsetActiveCell.Offset(0, -7)
```

Comment: Dane, thank you.  It's amazing how much help you can get from just having another set of eyes on an issue.  I'm no expert, but a little embarrassed that the problem was literally staring me in the face.  Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. If my answer helped you out, please accept it as the answer

Comment: Sorry for my "newbieness" on the site, but where do I go to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code repeats `ActiveCell.Offset`. This repetition needs to be removed.